# Word for "a thing that is derived from."

Tags: single-word-requests

I have some code containing "derivations" which are values that update automatically when any of the values it uses are updated.  They are derived from these sub-values, but I don't know what to call them.

I could have sworn there was a math term for it, but I can't seem to find it.

As an example of the term, I've tried searching "derivee" and "derivation source," and checked the thesaurus for "derive."

Is there a single word for the values from which another value is derived?

Also, these aren't arguments for a function, but more like a column in a spreadsheet which some other column is dependent on.

Comment: If the values are *automatically* updated, I'd say they're ***live*** (feasibly, ***hot***). Programmers have a related concept called ***volatile*** variables (which can be modified by processes other than the main execution thread of a program).

Comment: I would have thought they were "dependent variables" (which change based on one or more independent variables) but I'm not certain enough of math terminology to make that an answer.

Comment: Your term *source* works well here. The derived values were based on (those of) the *source*.

Comment: Have you tried putting this question on mathematics?

Comment: I had definitely thought source multiple times, but it's rather ambiguous.  Another word that seems related (and under the umbrella of source) is a "clue," though that doesn't work in the math world at all.  Still, the notion that ideas are the byproduct of clues, is similar to derivations are the byproduct of...

Comment: @Tuffy I have not.  If it lasts more than a day here, I'll try over there.

Comment: Also, though it is not an actual word, a "derivate" would be a reasonable term for this, and given my case has more to do with making machine logic human readable than it does with proper english, it might work in my context.  Still not an appropriate answer though.

Comment: Grammatically: if *X* is derived from *Y*, then we say that *X* is a derivative of *Y*.

Comment: The term for the thing from which other things are derived is *original*.

Comment: I would have thought **data set** or **sample**, but I'm surprised that nobody else has mentioned either, so maybe I'm misinterpreting the question.

Comment: maybe datum (not data set), but in comp sci land datum is a very vague word.  Sample is good though.  Perhaps a word like sample, but the entirety is always consumed.  Samples you just take a little piece of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I've heard the simple term 'precursor' used in a mathematical sense.

> **precursor**  n.
>
> 1. [A person, situation etc – licensed by the example] that precedes and indicates, suggests, or announces someone or something to come

[[AHD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/precursor)]

The 'source giving rise to a related entity' implication is certainly present in the chemical usage:

> **precursor** 3. (Chemistry)
>
> a chemical substance that gives rise to another ... substance

[[Collins](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/precursor)]

and in the biology usage:

> **precursor** 4
>
> a cell or tissue that gives rise to a variant ... form.

[[RHK Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/precursor)]

Comment: "derivations are the byproduct of precursors" and "derive the precursors into a derivation" both seem to function pretty well as statements.

Answer (score 1):

How about *independent variable*?

> Independent variables are the variables that the experimenter changes
>   to test their dependent variable. A change in the independent variable
>   directly causes a change in the dependent variable

https://www.thoughtco.com/definition-of-independent-variable-605238

Comment: While this would be nice for a more front-of-the-function perspective, it doesn't work as well for back-of-the-function thinking. From the back side, the function can't be reached, and the variables aren't manipulable, they're just part of the cause.